# Best way to check if a Variable is nil?

Tags: delphi, pointers

A common condition that all programs should do is to check if variables are assigned or not.

Take the below statements:

**(1)**

```
if Assigned(Ptr) then
begin
  // do something
end;
```

**(2)**

```
if Ptr <> nil then
begin
  // do something
end;
```

What is the difference between `Assigned(Ptr)` and `Ptr <> nil`?

Comment: See the http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Assigned

Comment: "Which is better?" What are your criteria?

Comment: Results can differ.. see my answer below...

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It's usually the same... except when you check a function...

```
function mfi: TObject;
begin
  Result := nil;
end;

procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
type
  TMyFunction = function: TObject of object;
var
  f: TMyFunction;
begin
  f := mfi;

  if Assigned(f) then
  begin
    ShowMessage('yes'); // TRUE
  end
  else
  begin
    ShowMessage('no');
  end;

  if f <> nil then
  begin
    ShowMessage('yes');
  end
  else
  begin
    ShowMessage('no');  // FALSE
  end;
end;
```

With the second syntax, it will check the result of the function, not the function itself...

Answer (score 5):

As far as performance, there is no difference. I personally prefer the second form as I find that humans can parse the meaning quicker.

Comment: Very odd human that finds `<>nil` easier to read than assigned. I personally prefer the exact opposite for the exact same reason. In other words I think option 1 is easier to parse.

Comment: I would also say `if Assigned` to be more human readable rather than <> operands.

Comment: I think the reason is that at first glance Assigned can be any old function call.

Comment: I also prefer Assigned.  Easier to read and "safer".  It always behaves the same, unlike this example with "F: TMyFunction".  What really bugs me is working in a code base where both are used.  For someone who doesn't know better, it leads to the very question the OP asked.  "What is the difference, and why is one here but another there?"