# E2015 In Delphi using Edit Boxes

Tags: delphi

I have three Edit boxes, these are used to feed Parameters into a query for my database, which in return executes and returns the desired results. This all works, the problem I'm having is this
:

```
 if ((DayOfWeekSCH.Text) and (EndTimeSCH.Text) and (StartTimeSCH.Text)) <> '' then
```

`DayOfWeekSCH`, `EndTimeSCH` and `StartTimeSCH` are all edit boxes, what I'm attempting to do, is make sure these boxes aren't empty before executing the code to execute the query. But I'm getting the `E2015 Error` which I don't understand why I'm getting it.

EDIT: This is the full error code:

> [dcc32 Error] PAvailableForm.pas(37): E2015 Operator not applicable to this operand type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> E2015: Operator not applicable to this operand type

where `<string> and <string>` does not make sense since `and` is interpreted as a boolean or bitwise operator, depending on its operands: hence the error.

See [Boolean Operators](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Expressions_(Delphi)#Boolean_Operators) and [Logical (Bitwise) Operators](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Expressions_(Delphi)#Logical_.28Bitwise.29_Operators).

It seems you want to achieve something like this:

```
if DayOfWeekSCH.Text + EndTimeSCH.Text + StartTimeSCH.Text <> '' then
```

Anyway the above is a wrong way to perform a string comparison.
You might want to see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10619801/what-is-the-better-way-to-check-for-an-empty-string-in-delphi/10620303#10620303) on how to check if a string is empty.

Related to the question, since an edit box, say a `TEdit`, descends from `TControl`, the [`GetTextLen`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.GetTextLen) method can be used in order to check the text buffer size: if `0` the text is empty.

```
if (DayOfWeekSCH.GetTextLen > 0) and (EndTimeSCH.GetTextLen > 0) and (StartTimeSCH.GetTextLen > 0) then
```

Comment: `if DayOfWeekSCH.Text + EndTimeSCH.Text + StartTimeSCH.Text <> '' then`is awful. String allocation/manipulation at runtime to avoid a few keystrokes while coding???

Comment: @UliGerhardt "Your code should be as follows:" is misleading: gonna change

Comment: The asker certainly doesn't want to concatenate and you should remove that from your answer.

Comment: Consider using this instead: `if (DayOfWeekSCH.GetTextLen > 0) and (EndTimeSCH.GetTextLen > 0) and (StartTimeSCH.GetTextLen > 0) then`. There is no point in wasting memory or computations to allocate `String` objects that are not going to be used for anything other than checking their lengths. Edit controls know their own text lengths, so just ask directly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau  I didn't know about `GetTextLen` before and I've never used it. Anyway the text concatenation example, in my intention it was obviously an *how-not-to-do-it* example but it didn't appear like that for how I wrote it down since all the comments point it out. Answer edited, thank you all.